# How make chunking work with amazonka, conduit and lazy bytestring

Tags: haskell, conduit

I wrote the code below to simulate upload to `S3` from `Lazy ByteString` (which will be received over the network socket. Here, we simulate by reading from a file of size ~100MB). The problem with the code below is that it seems to be forcing the read of entire file into memory instead of chunking it (`cbytes`) - will appreciate pointers on why chunking is not working:

```
import Control.Lens
import Network.AWS
import Network.AWS.S3
import Network.AWS.Data.Body
import System.IO
import           Data.Conduit (($$+-))
import           Data.Conduit.Binary (sinkLbs,sourceLbs)
import qualified Data.Conduit.List as CL (mapM_)
import           Network.HTTP.Conduit (responseBody,RequestBody(..),newManager,tlsManagerSettings)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as LBS

example :: IO PutObjectResponse
example = do
    -- To specify configuration preferences, newEnv is used to create a new Env. The Region denotes the AWS region requests will be performed against,
    -- and Credentials is used to specify the desired mechanism for supplying or retrieving AuthN/AuthZ information.
    -- In this case, Discover will cause the library to try a number of options such as default environment variables, or an instance's IAM Profile:
    e <- newEnv NorthVirginia Discover

    -- A new Logger to replace the default noop logger is created, with the logger set to print debug information and errors to stdout:
    l <- newLogger Debug stdout

    -- The payload for the S3 object is retrieved from a file that simulates lazy bytestring received over network
    inb <- LBS.readFile "out"
    lenb <- System.IO.withFile "out" ReadMode hFileSize -- evaluates to 104857600 (100MB)
    let cbytes = toBody $ ChunkedBody (1024*128) (fromIntegral lenb) (sourceLbs inb)

    -- We now run the AWS computation with the overriden logger, performing the PutObject request:
    runResourceT . runAWS (e & envLogger .~ l) $
        send ((putObject "yourtestenv-change-it-please" "testbucket/test" cbytes) & poContentType .~ Just "text; charset=UTF-8")

main = example >> return ()
```

Running the executable with `RTS -s` option shows that entire thing is read into memory (~113MB maximum residency - I did see ~87MB once). On the other hand, if I use [`chunkedFile`](http://haddock.stackage.org/nightly-2015-10-23/amazonka-1.3.3.1/src/Network.AWS.Internal.Body.html#chunkedFile), it is chunked correctly (~10MB maximum residency).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's clear this bit

```
  inb <- LBS.readFile "out"
  lenb <- System.IO.withFile "out" ReadMode hFileSize -- evaluates to 104857600 (100MB)
  let cbytes = toBody $ ChunkedBody (1024*128) (fromIntegral lenb) (sourceLbs inb)
```

should be rewritten as

```
  lenb <- System.IO.withFile "out" ReadMode hFileSize -- evaluates to 104857600 (100MB)
  let cbytes = toBody $ ChunkedBody (1024*128) (fromIntegral lenb) (C.sourceFile "out")
```

As you wrote it, the purpose of conduits is defeated. The entire file would need to be accumulated by `LBS.readFile`, but then broken apart chunk by chunk when fed to `sourceLBS`. (If lazy IO is working right, this might not happen.) `sourceFile` reads the file incrementally, chunk by chunk. It may be that, e.g. `toBody` accumulates the whole file, in which case the point of conduits is defeated at a different point.  Glancing at the source for `send` and so on I can't see anything that would do this, though.

Comment: How would one simulate lazy bytestring then? I need to simulate it since it is coming over the network socket, not a file handle. I thought `sourceLbs` would take care of reading the lazy bytestring incrementally.

Comment: Well, as it stands you are getting the simulating bytes from a file, so why not use `sourceFile`? Later you will replace `sourceFile "out"` with a conduit source that reads from a socket, no?

Comment: Oh wait ... there will be the further complication of getting the total length. Will the source tell you that in advance?

Comment: total length can be easily supplied ahead of time by the source - I have already thought about it. So, yep, I can simulate like what you suggested. Just wanted to get confirmation that it is the way to go.

Comment: Yes, that seems right. There will be the complication of e.g. first parsing the length from the source/socket and then feeding the remainder to `toBody $ ChunkedBody ...`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I think the culprit is `LBS.readFile` its [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.8.1/docs/Data-ByteString-Lazy.html#v:readFile) says:

> ```
> readFile :: FilePath -> IO ByteString
>
> Read an entire file lazily into a ByteString.
> The Handle will be held open until EOF is encountered.
> ```

`chunkedFile` works in the way of conduit - alternatively you could use

```
sourceFile :: MonadResource m => FilePath -> Producer m ByteString
```

from ([`conduit-extras/Data.Conduit.Binary`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-extra-1.1.13.1)) instead of `LBS.readFile`, but I am not an expert.